# Don't understand this Can't Use Function Return error

Tags: php, function, return

I'm having to manually edit a file that's whiting out my forum pages and the error that the PHP validator kicks out is:  Can't Use Function Return In Write Context.  The line in question is:

```
$canSeePrivateTopics = !empty($modSettings['PrivateTopics_enable']) ? allowedTo('can_always_see_private_topics') = true;
```

The surrounding code is:

```
$posts = array();
$canSeePrivateTopics = !empty($modSettings['PrivateTopics_enable']) ? allowedTo('can_always_see_private_topics') = true;

while ($row = $smcFunc['db_fetch_assoc']($request))
{
    if (empty($canSeePrivateTopics) && !empty($row['private_users']))
    {
        $ptusers = PrivateTopics_decode($row['private_users']);

        if (!empty($ptusers) && !isset($ptUsers[$user_info['id']]))
            continue;
    }
    $row['body'] = parse_bbc($row['body'], $row['smileys_enabled'], $row['id_msg']);
```

I'm afraid I don't understand how to correct it, since I'm so very new at this.  Any help would be so appreciated!

Comment: What are you trying to do? You can't assign a value to the result of a function call. Did you mean `$canSeePrivateTopics = !empty($modSettings['PrivateTopics_enable']) ? allowedTo('can_always_see_private_topics') : true;`?

Comment: First, let me say that what you suggested seems to have worked beautifully!  I can see my forum again!  :o)     To be honest, I don't know a lot about PHP and only knew that I had to track down the source of the glitch in the forum.  I gleaned over the files one by one and this one is the one that kicked out and I traced it to a mod.  Thank you, @Chris, so much!  I'm unsure of how to mark your answer as the solution?

Comment: To answer your very last question: @Chris should post a "real" answer. But he didn't, because he hasn't been notified of your comment. Notification of a comment is sent only: 1) to the author of the current post (OP or answer). To <somebody> if your comment contains "@<somebody>" (as I did here, so he'll be now notified).

Comment: Thanks @cFreed. Indeed I hadn't seen that. I've made an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of your ternary expression seems to be incorrect. It should be

```
$canSeePrivateTopics = !empty($modSettings['PrivateTopics_enable']) ? allowedTo('can_always_see_private_topics') : true;
```

instead.